# Turkey goes Tweet -- java cannot symbol error

Tags: java, tweets

I'm attempting to build the raspberry pi turkey tweeter from an article at the following:

https://blogs.oracle.com/hinkmond/entry/internet_of_things_iot_thanksgiving2

Everything so far is working mechanically but I cannot get the provided code to work. It is giving the following errors (just the first 2 for space) when I try to compile:

```
TurkeyTweeter.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
    Date date = null;
    ^
  symbol:   class Date
  location: class TurkeyTweeter
TurkeyTweeter.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        ^
  symbol:   class FileInputStream
  location: class TurkeyTweeter
TurkeyTweeter.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        ^
  symbol:   class DataInputStream
  location: class TurkeyTweeter
```

I only provided the first 2 errors to save space and because I believe there is an underlying issues that causes the rest of the errors.

Any ideas are welcome. I'll post the complete recipe once it is complete.

Comment: did you `import` the required classes? (hint: no)

Comment: good call Doorknob. i should have mentioned that i don't normally work in java

Comment: i'm struggling to figure out which classes are required so that i can import. advice?

Comment: `Date`, `FileInputStream`, and `DataInputStream` perhaps?

Comment: Tried that in this way -- maybe my syntax is incorrect:import Date.*;
import FileInputStream.*;
import DataInputStream.*;

Answer (score 2):

Add the following lines after your package name or the top of the file, but before your class declaration.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
```

[image]

You can view all the Java documentations here:

- [Java Docs Landing page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/api-jsp-136079.html)
- [Java 6 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)
- [Java 7 Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class FileNotFoundException
  location: class TurkeyTweeter

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
            } catch (IOException ioe1) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class IOException
  location: class TurkeyTweeter

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
            date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable Calendar
  location: class TurkeyTweeter

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d kk:mm:ss");
            ^
  symbol:   class Format
  location: class TurkeyTweeter

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
            Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d kk:mm:ss");
            ^
  symbol:   class Format
  location: class TurkeyTweeter

Comment: TurkeyTweeter.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
            } catch (IOException e) {
                     ^
  symbol:   class IOException
  location: class TurkeyTweeter
6 errors

Comment: Are you a compiler? You can import the whole `IO` library by using: `import java.io.*` Use "CTRL+F" in your browser and search for the class you are missing; using the documantation links I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that! I left out the import lines for brevity in my blog post. Here they all are:

```
// For USB Device Reading
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

// For Tweeting
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.CookiePolicy;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.Format;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
```

Let me know if you still see problems after adding these.

Thanks,
Hinkmond